# Google Places AutoComplete API gives API_NOT_CONNECTED error in Instant Apps configuration

Tags: android, kotlin, google-play-services, google-places-api, android-instant-apps

I am trying to add Google Places AutoComplete API to my Android Instant Apps project.

I followed [this sample](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-play-places/blob/master/PlaceCompleteAdapter/Application/src/main/java/com/example/google/playservices/placecomplete/PlaceAutocompleteAdapter.java) to implement the API.

My `PlacesAdapter` class:

```
package net.epictimes.uvindex.autocomplete

import android.content.Context
import android.graphics.Typeface
import android.text.style.StyleSpan
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter
import android.widget.Filter
import android.widget.Filterable
import android.widget.TextView
import com.google.android.gms.common.data.DataBufferUtils
import com.google.android.gms.location.places.AutocompletePrediction
import com.google.android.gms.location.places.GeoDataClient
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLngBounds
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.RuntimeExecutionException
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Tasks
import timber.log.Timber
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit
import java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException


class PlacesAdapter(context: Context, private val geoDataClient: GeoDataClient)
    : ArrayAdapter<AutocompletePrediction>(context, android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_2, android.R.id.text1), Filterable {

    private val resultList = mutableListOf<AutocompletePrediction>()
    private val styleBold = StyleSpan(Typeface.BOLD)

    override fun getCount(): Int = resultList.size

    override fun getItem(position: Int): AutocompletePrediction = resultList[position]

    override fun getView(position: Int, convertView: View?, parent: ViewGroup?): View {
        val row = super.getView(position, convertView, parent)

        // Sets the primary and secondary text for a row.
        // Note that getPrimaryText() and getSecondaryText() return a CharSequence that may contain
        // styling based on the given CharacterStyle.

        val item = getItem(position)

        val textView1 = row.findViewById<View>(android.R.id.text1) as TextView
        val textView2 = row.findViewById<View>(android.R.id.text2) as TextView
        textView1.text = item.getPrimaryText(styleBold)
        textView2.text = item.getSecondaryText(styleBold)

        return row
    }

    override fun getFilter(): Filter {
        return object : Filter() {
            override fun performFiltering(constraint: CharSequence?): FilterResults {
                val results = FilterResults()

                // We need a separate list to store the results, since
                // this is run asynchronously.
                var filterData: ArrayList<AutocompletePrediction>? = ArrayList()

                // Skip the autocomplete query if no constraints are given.
                if (constraint != null) {
                    // Query the autocomplete API for the (constraint) search string.
                    filterData = getAutocomplete(constraint)
                }

                results.values = filterData
                if (filterData != null) {
                    results.count = filterData.size
                } else {
                    results.count = 0
                }

                return results
            }

            override fun publishResults(constraint: CharSequence?, results: FilterResults?) {
                if (results != null && results.count > 0) {
                    // The API returned at least one result, update the data.
                    resultList.clear()
                    resultList.addAll(results.values as ArrayList<AutocompletePrediction>)
                }

                notifyDataSetChanged()
            }

        }
    }

    /**
     * Submits an autocomplete query to the Places Geo Data Autocomplete API.
     * Results are returned as frozen AutocompletePrediction objects, ready to be cached.
     * Returns an empty list if no results were found.
     * Returns null if the API client is not available or the query did not complete
     * successfully.
     * This method MUST be called off the main UI thread, as it will block until data is returned
     * from the API, which may include a network request.
     *
     * @param constraint Autocomplete query string
     * @return Results from the autocomplete API or null if the query was not successful.
     * @see GeoDataClient.getAutocompletePredictions
     * @see AutocompletePrediction.freeze
     */
    private fun getAutocomplete(constraint: CharSequence): ArrayList<AutocompletePrediction>? {
        Timber.d("Starting autocomplete query for: " + constraint)

        val latLngBounds = LatLngBounds(LatLng(-34.041458, 150.790100), LatLng(-33.682247, 151.383362))

        // Submit the query to the autocomplete API and retrieve a PendingResult that will
        // contain the results when the query completes.
        val results = geoDataClient.getAutocompletePredictions(constraint.toString(), latLngBounds, null)

        // This method should have been called off the main UI thread. Block and wait for at most
        // 60s for a result from the API.
        try {
            Tasks.await(results, 60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        } catch (e: ExecutionException) {
            Timber.e(e)
        } catch (e: InterruptedException) {
            Timber.e(e)
        } catch (e: TimeoutException) {
            Timber.e(e)
        }

        Timber.d("Query completed. Received " + results.result.count + " predictions.")

        return try {
            // Freeze the results immutable representation that can be stored safely.
            DataBufferUtils.freezeAndClose<AutocompletePrediction, AutocompletePrediction>(results.result)
        } catch (e: RuntimeExecutionException) {
            // If the query did not complete successfully return null
            Timber.e("Error getting autocomplete prediction API call", e)
            null
        }

    }
}
```

When I run the project in `app` configuration **it works fine**.

But when I run it in `instantapp` configuration it throws this:

```
D/PlacesAdapter: Starting autocomplete query for: is
E/GmsClient: unable to connect to service: com.google.android.gms.location.places.GeoDataApi on com.google.android.gms
E/PlacesAdapter: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 17: API_NOT_CONNECTED
                     at com.google.android.gms.tasks.Tasks.zzc(Unknown Source:17)
                     at com.google.android.gms.tasks.Tasks.await(Unknown Source:53)
                     at net.epictimes.uvindex.autocomplete.PlacesAdapter.getAutocomplete(PlacesAdapter.kt:116)
                     at net.epictimes.uvindex.autocomplete.PlacesAdapter.access$getAutocomplete(PlacesAdapter.kt:25)
                     at net.epictimes.uvindex.autocomplete.PlacesAdapter$getFilter$1.performFiltering(PlacesAdapter.kt:64)
                     at android.widget.Filter$RequestHandler.handleMessage(Filter.java:234)
                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
                     at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:65)
                  Caused by: com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 17: API_NOT_CONNECTED
                     at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzb.zzz(Unknown Source:14)
                     at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzbk.zzaa(Unknown Source:0)
                     at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzbl.zzs(Unknown Source:32)
                     at com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.zzs.zzc(Unknown Source:46)
                     at com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.zzs.setResult(Unknown Source:42)
                     at com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.zzm.zzv(Unknown Source:17)
                     at com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.zzc.zzt(Unknown Source:2)
                     at com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.zzbr.zzx(Unknown Source:27)
                     at com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.zzbp.handleMessage(Unknown Source:386)
                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:101)
                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
                     at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:65) 
W/Filter: An exception occured during performFiltering()!
          com.google.android.gms.tasks.RuntimeExecutionException: com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 17: API_NOT_CONNECTED
              at com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzn.getResult(Unknown Source:14)
              at net.epictimes.uvindex.autocomplete.PlacesAdapter.getAutocomplete(PlacesAdapter.kt:123)
              at net.epictimes.uvindex.autocomplete.PlacesAdapter.access$getAutocomplete(PlacesAdapter.kt:25)
              at net.epictimes.uvindex.autocomplete.PlacesAdapter$getFilter$1.performFiltering(PlacesAdapter.kt:64)
              at android.widget.Filter$RequestHandler.handleMessage(Filter.java:234)
              at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
              at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
              at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:65)
           Caused by: com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 17: API_NOT_CONNECTED
              at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzb.zzz(Unknown Source:14)
              at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzbk.zzaa(Unknown Source:0)
              at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzbl.zzs(Unknown Source:32)
              at com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.zzs.zzc(Unknown Source:46)
              at com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.zzs.setResult(Unknown Source:42)
              at com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.zzm.zzv(Unknown Source:17)
              at com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.zzc.zzt(Unknown Source:2)
              at com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.zzbr.zzx(Unknown Source:27)
              at com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.zzbp.handleMessage(Unknown Source:386)
              at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:101)
              at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
              at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:65)
```

`API_NOT_CONNECTED` error code's explation in the [docs](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/api/CommonStatusCodes.html#API_NOT_CONNECTED):

> The client attempted to call a method from an API that failed to
>   connect. Possible reasons include:
>
> - The API previously failed to connect with a resolvable error, but the    user declined the resolution.
> - The device does not support GmsCore.
> - The specific API cannot connect on this device.

I updated the Google Play Services on the emulator (it's 11.7.46 (470-175121617) BTW) but it didn't changed anyting.

I put my Google Play Services dependencies into the `base` module. I checked the merged manifest files, they all have the Google Play API keys.

In the [Android Developers site](https://developer.android.com/topic/instant-apps/getting-started/prepare.html#identifying_tested_compatible_libraries) they listed Google Places API in the **supported** API list.

I am using Google Location API in the other feature module and it is working in both `app` and `instantapp` configurations.

So what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Can you file a bug to Google, then link to it back in here? It would be helpful for all, thanks! https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=316045&template=1018787

Comment: You can also try using the `PlaceAutocompleteFragment`

Answer (score 0):

I decided to connect the API using the GoogleApiClient:

```
GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .enableAutoManage(this, this)
                .addApi(Places.GEO_DATA_API)
                .build()
                .connect()
```

But the connection attempt failed with status code `API_UNAVAILABLE` in `instantapp` configuration.

In the [docs](https://developer.android.com/topic/instant-apps/getting-started/prepare.html#identifying_tested_compatible_libraries), `API_UNAVAILABLE` means that the API is not available for Instant Apps:

> When debugging an instant app that uses a Google Play services library
>   other than those included in the list above, you may see the
>   API_UNAVAILABLE error in your debugging output. The API_UNAVAILABLE
>   error indicates that the library has not been adapted for usage in
>   Android Instant Apps.

So I dropped the Places AutoComplete and continued with something similar like [geocoding](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Geocoder.html).