# PlaceAutocomplete not working in Instant App

Tags: android, google-places, android-instant-apps

I am trying to convert one of my apps to instant apps and PlaceAutocomplete is an important part of the app. But I am unable to find any documentation or any way in how to use PlaceAutocomplete in Instant app.

I am using this code

```
try {
         Intent intent = new PlaceAutocomplete.IntentBuilder(PlaceAutocomplete.MODE_OVERLAY)
                            .build(getActivity());
         startActivityForResult(intent, PLACE_AUTOCOMPLETE_REQUEST_CODE);
    } catch (GooglePlayServicesRepairableException e) {
         Log.e("Place Autocomplete",e.getLocalizedMessage());
    } catch (GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException e) {
         Log.e("Place Autocomplete",e.getLocalizedMessage());
    }
```

and it's working fine in Installed version but when the same code is executed in instant app version this error is thrown and app crashes.

```
No Activity found to handle Intent { act=com.google.android.gms.location.places.ui.AUTOCOMPLETE pkg=com.google.android.gms (has extras) }
```

Issue report.

I am using

```
api 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:16.0.0'
api 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:16.0.0'
```

in my baseFeature and

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:16.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:16.0.0'
```

in my feature module.

I have also added google-services.json and added `apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services' in my app module.

So, what am I doing wrong and if PlaceAutocomplete does not support Instant what are the alternates I can use.
`

Comment: Have you tried to run your instant app on pre-O device? For me PlaceAutocomplete works fine on pre-O, but crashes on O+.
If you can see the same behavior, can you file a bug at https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=316045&template=1018787 and link to it back in here?

Comment: Sorry for the delay. I have already opened an issue on issue tracker https://issuetracker.google.com/118398809 . I was not able to test it on pre oreo devices but worked around by using current user location till this problem gets resolved.

Comment: It doesn't look like this API is available for Instant Apps yet, also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47580594/google-places-autocomplete-api-gives-api-not-connected-error-in-instant-apps-con I just tried all the PlacesComplete samples @ https://github.com/googlesamples/android-play-places and none of them worked for O+

Comment: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/80149649 and based on this issue link they are not going to fix it in future I guess.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue. It s not working for android 8.0 or upper.

In this case, I m not using the place autocomplete from the library but I implemented the my own auto completion textview with the google maps api (https).

I keep using the other feature of the google map android lib. Only this part was bringing a blocker to deploy.

Comment: I went through the issue you raised and couldn't understand why they updated status as `Won't Fix (Obsolete)`.

Comment: But that should not be the case. As many users are facing this problem.